# Trying to share a Post on Facebook twitter LinkedIn on third parties account unable to post or share using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to upload an image and share on all social media of third party. So how to share my post on the third party account using the Laravel. As i am new to this field so please help me. I don't know how to do it.

This is for Facebook what i have created to share the details.

.env File

```
FACEBOOK_ID=1xxxxxx2
FACEBOOK_SECRET=9xxxxxxxxxxxxx8
FACEBOOK_URL=http://localhost:8000/login/facebook/callback

config/service.php file
'facebook_poster' => [
    'app_id'    => getenv('FACEBOOK_APP_ID'),
    'app_secret' => getenv('FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'),
    'access_token'    => getenv('FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN'),
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/login/facebook/callback',
    ],
```

uploadfilecontroller
This is my controller to upload image and share on facebook.

```
function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'select_file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048'
        ]);
        // dd('done');
        $image = $request->file('select_file');
        $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move(public_path("images"), $new_name);

        SendTo::Facebook(
                    'photo',
                    [
                        'photo' => public_path('images/'.$new_name),
                        //Test this and we will up date the discription
                        'message' => 'The discription goes here !!'
                    ]
                );

        return back()->with('success','Image Uploaded Successfully')
                     ->with('path', $new_name);

        $user = new file;
        $user->name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $user->save();
        return 'data saved in database.';
    }
```

view as upload.blade.php

This is my view file to dispaly share button of facebook.

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('/uploadfile')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="{{Route('home')}}" data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true">
             <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you jut post the credentials here

Comment: Is it fine now..? @C2486

Comment: No, it's not OK, there is edit history. You should delete the question

Comment: should I delete and repost the question ..?@Braca

Comment: s please repost it @Braca

Comment: The problem with your question is that you have facebook secret publicly visible.

Comment: can u please mail me at amrutapatil599@gmail.com so that i can brief u@Braca

Comment: plz reply i am unable to fix this problem... @Braca